# How to implement Asp.net identity for authentication and authorization using service stack V3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, servicestack, asp.net-identity

How to implement Asp.net identity for authentication and authorization using service stack V3 with SQL Server as back-end managing users, roles and membership

Comment: http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-identity-stripped-bare-mvc-part-1

Comment: http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-identity-stripped-bare-mvc-part-2

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft's ASP.NET Identity provider provides a way to do Auth/Authz in ASP.NET code with a SQL backend. You can write your own provider if you are motivated.

ServiceStack's built-in AuthProvider provides it's own independent way to do Auth/Authz over ASP.NET with a SQL backend. You can also write your own provider.

The two do not share any code, models, or interfaces.

If you want to implement the ASP.NET Identity model using the ServiceStack AuthProvider model, you would have to customize the ServiceStack provider with code from the ASP.NET Identity provider.

To customize ServiceStack AuthProvider v3, try my blog post:
[Customizing IAuthProvider for ServiceStack.net – Step by Step](http://enehana.nohea.com/general/customizing-iauthprovider-for-servicestack-net-step-by-step/)

Then you could stick in the ASP.NET Identity code. The articles [ASP.NET Identity Stripped Bare - MVC Part 1](http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-identity-stripped-bare-mvc-part-1) ( @dr-net mentions) will show you what you are in for.

You would have to decide if its worth it - you probably want to just pick one or the other, instead of trying to mash them together.

FYI- the ServiceStack v3 and v4 Auth code are somewhat different - at least some refactoring done.